# How to supply user information for CreateProcess?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

How to supply user's information inside the CreateProcess function? Below is my current work. It seems cannot call my external exe. But when I run it manually inside console, it runs well.

```
if (CreateProcess(parameterA.GetBuffer(), parameterB.GetBuffer(),0,0,TRUE,
          NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS|CREATE_NO_WINDOW,0,0,&sInfo,&pInfo))
          {
            WaitForSingleObject (pInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
          }
```

parameterA = "myapp.exe";
parameterB = " -i";

Comment: How to change this code to do CreateProcess with admin rights?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument may be null - you specify the process path in the second argument only. Please show us what `parameterB` is. You also need to to initialize STARTUPINFO properly.